How to deploy Angular 18 SSR on Nginx manually
I have built project home-aap with Angular 18 and SSR enabled. Now Angular 18 comes with built in SSR, So after executing ng build it has generated below folders:
[enter image description here][1]
/var/www/dist/home-app/browser
/var/www/dist/home-app/server
Below is home-config for Nginx:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost; # Change to your domain

    # Serve static files directly from the browser build
    location / {
        root /var/www/dist/home-app/browser; # Adjust to your actual path
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # Fallback to index.html for SPA
    }

    # Serve dynamic SSR content for specific routes
    location /ssr {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; # Node server
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Above is successfully linked in sites-enabled folder:
[enter image description here][2]
Also, server.mjs is running at localhost:4000:
[enter image description here][3]
So if I visit localhost, Nginx throws 403:
[enter image description here][4]
But if I visit http://localhost:4000/, app is loading successfully:
[enter image description here][5]
But why its not loading at localhost.
I have checked Angular official page but there is not much much regarding manual deployment on server or VPS.
https://angular.dev/tools/cli/deployment
It would be really helpful if anyone can suggest how to properly deploy angular 18 with SSR activate on Nginx on server/VPS manually.
Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/BOF3LDRz.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/lQKzVbf9.png
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/jtDJYl5F.png
[4]: https://i.sstatic.net/26x62XzM.png
[5]: https://i.sstatic.net/CNjjQlrk.png

you need to be running the ssr server to be able to navigate to your /ssr path and rendering. I would lookup pm2 which can help you manage node apps running. It can autostart etc on restarts of the server etc. Used it in the past for SSR of ng14

I think I’m already running ssr server by running command ‘node server.mjs’, and it’s running at localhost:4000. Correct me if I’m missing something here

you miight need to run it as a deamon, but if you can curl to it in terminal it should work

I found the resolution, In Angular 18 dist/browser folder contains  index.csr.html instead of index.html, so we have to conf file Nginx accordingly.
Below is the updated code for home-app.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Serve static files for CSR
    location / {
        root /var/www/dist/home-app/browser;
        index index.csr.html;  # Set index.csr.html as the default index file
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.csr.html;  # Fallback to index.csr.html for CSR
    }

    # Serve dynamic SSR content for specific routes
    location /ssr {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;  # Forward requests to your Node.js SSR server
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

